# Multiple GUI Threads in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface

As mentioned in Qt documentation, each program has one "main thread" (also known as the "GUI thread") when it is started. The Qt GUI must run in this thread. All widgets and several related classes, for example QPixmap, don't work in secondary threads.

So you can not have GUI components in any worker thread in anyway.

I have some questions related to this topic:

1. Is there any workaround or hack in a Qt implementation which does not force this mechanism?
2. Is it probable that this restriction be omitted in a far future release of Qt?

Comment: It seems [they say that](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/16552-Starting-QT-GUI-in-a-seperate-Thread) the gui thread is where the application lives, not necessarily the main thread despite the documentation, so I imagine a better wording would be how to do it in different threads, but it would also be good to see some use cases for it why it is necessary.

Comment: @LaszloPapp In some situations you need to use some heavy paintings or pixmap related operations repeatedly in high speed which blocks the main thread in some intervals and causes the application to be slow.

Comment: For an other example Qt's ActiveX Framework (ActiveQt) should be on main thread which causes the application to be unresponsive to certain events in an activex if the main thread is busy for some milliseconds.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by heavy painting?

Comment: @LaszloPapp For example imagine you have multiple high quality graphs with anti-aliasing and alpha effects in a plotting library like QCustomPlot and you need to update your plots repeatedly. This causes the main thread to be blocked in certain intervals.

Comment: 1) Cannot you move all the computation out of the gui thread? 2) What is the problem with "blocking" (async)? 3) Cannot you do other things in a different thread if needed? 4) What GUI action would you like to do for the gui besides plotting, simultaneously?

Comment: @LaszloPapp You can not move all of the GUI computations. Atleast bulk of it should remain in main thread. For the example of QCustomPlot it inherits QWidget and there is no way to put it in another thread. When the main thread is blocked, other GUI elements get unresponsive at that moment.

Comment: Perhaps, QCustomPlot shall be fixed? Just the rendering without computation should not take noticeable blocking IMHO.

Comment: QCustomPlot has no way because much of the bulk work is GUI related. One render does not take much time but when you want to render complex  graphs for instance 10 times a second then the blocking gets annoying.

Comment: Looks like you need to initialize QT for a different thread than main thread. Does [this discussion](http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/41152) answer your question?

Comment: @Nejat: I personally render games with good FPS in the main thread without blocking. Perhaps, when it gets to raytracing and that category.. but then you have qt opengl and opencl classes to aid the rendering without which (GPU and GPGPU) it is somewhat unusual to render complex graphics these days.